# Getting different values in a rectangular array when initialized from a text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, grid, numbers, streamreader

I'm trying to initialize a two-dimensional array from a text file containing a 20x20 grid of numbers (separated by spaces) **using vb.NET in Visual Studio 2013**. I've tweaked my loops to work correctly but the values I get from the streamreader are totally differently from what is in the file.

Here's the vb code

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
Dim grid(19, 19) As String

Sub Main()
    Dim deskPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
    Using upload As New StreamReader(deskPath & "\grid.txt")
        'Console.WriteLine(upload.ReadToEnd)

        For x As Integer = 0 To 19

            For y As Integer = 0 To 19
                grid(x, y) = upload.Read() '& upload.read()
                upload.Read()
            Next

        Next
    End Using

Using outfile As New StreamWriter(deskPath & "\Result1.txt")
        For y As Integer = 0 To 19
            For x As Integer = 0 To 19
                outfile.Write(grid(x, y))
                outfile.Write(" ")
            Next
            outfile.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
End Module
```

This is the source file's content

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

And this is what the array is receiving

```
48 56 56 13 32 32 57 50 48 50 55 50 32 32 32 51 48 52 54 52 
32 53 53 56 56 49 13 32 32 53 53 54 52 56 53 32 32 32 50 52 
50 32 32 32 51 52 50 48 53 13 32 32 50 57 48 51 48 54 32 32 
50 50 48 57 32 32 32 52 48 51 52 50 13 32 32 57 48 51 53 55 
32 53 56 51 51 57 49 32 32 32 55 50 50 51 54 13 32 32 53 52 
55 32 32 32 52 50 49 56 52 56 32 32 32 49 52 55 50 49 13 32 
51 55 55 51 32 32 32 54 55 56 54 53 53 32 32 32 49 52 56 48 
32 57 52 53 51 56 49 32 32 32 49 54 53 56 48 55 32 32 32 50 
53 32 32 32 51 53 53 51 51 56 32 32 32 51 52 53 52 53 54 32 
48 56 56 57 32 32 32 49 53 54 56 52 53 32 32 32 48 53 48 56 
32 10 52 49 53 49 55 32 32 32 54 51 54 57 53 56 32 32 32 53 
48 57 32 32 10 51 54 48 56 51 32 32 32 54 49 50 51 56 56 32 
48 52 57 57 50 32 32 10 51 54 48 51 51 32 32 32 53 50 51 52 
32 32 52 57 55 54 57 52 32 32 10 48 57 50 48 53 32 32 32 49 
53 57 32 32 32 55 52 52 52 48 55 32 32 10 54 51 50 48 49 32 
48 52 52 49 53 32 32 32 50 50 50 48 54 49 32 32 10 49 56 56 
32 32 53 52 50 55 50 50 32 32 32 57 57 51 51 55 54 32 32 10 
53 55 32 32 32 48 51 54 53 56 48 32 32 32 57 49 51 52 55 57 
48 56 50 55 52 32 32 32 49 52 54 54 55 51 32 32 32 50 48 56 
32 32 48 53 54 54 52 57 32 32 32 52 55 48 52 52 53 32 32 32
```

I've tried finding patterns if the values were being saved in the wrong element, changing the datatype of the array and even casting the streamreader into int (that just gave an error). As you may have noticed I concatenated two read() operations to initialize two digits in each element but that gave me totally different (unrelatable to the 2 digit wrong values) 4 digit values. These ones

```
4856 1052 1310 5313 5749 3256 5032 5452 3257 5732 5149 3253 5432 5349 3248 5732 5150 3251 5732 5649 
4850 3252 4932 5350 1050 1310 4813 5548 3250 5132 5151 3253 5732 5352 3256 5132 5451 3252 5332 4954 
5050 3257 5732 5548 3251 5232 5150 1054 1310 5013 5753 3257 5332 4955 3253 5532 5751 3254 5232 5051 
5755 3252 4932 5753 3249 5532 5756 3250 5232 5049 1055 1310 5513 5356 3252 5632 5351 3255 5232 5355 
5156 3249 5132 5051 3255 5032 5649 3250 5332 5154 3249 5432 5654 1049 1310 5413 5457 3251 5432 4853 
4953 3256 5332 4852 3253 4832 5056 3254 5632 5051 3253 5732 5354 3256 5232 5656 1048 1310 5413 5352 
4848 3249 5732 5448 3254 5732 5452 3248 5332 4857 3250 5332 4848 3256 5032 5154 3252 4832 5048 1048 
5248 3253 5232 4949 3254 5132 5051 3254 5432 5553 3250 5032 5256 3254 5632 5456 3249 5732 5551 3255 
4848 3254 5732 5250 3256 5332 5455 3249 5132 4848 3255 5432 5153 3248 5132 5655 3255 5432 5153 3253 
5553 3256 5132 5457 3252 5032 4948 3250 5732 5554 3251 5332 5549 3257 5532 5355 3251 4932 5057 3255 
4852 3249 4932 5052 3257 5232 5054 3257 5432 5252 3254 4932 5657 3252 5332 5450 3250 5032 5556 3256 
4853 3252 4832 5456 3251 5332 5156 3254 5532 5048 3249 5532 4855 3254 5732 5048 3251 4832 5149 3253 
4855 3257 5532 5354 3253 5132 5248 3257 5532 5253 3257 5332 4853 3250 5432 5550 3249 5132 5748 3253 
5556 3252 5132 4849 3250 5132 5455 3251 5632 5153 3248 5632 5252 3255 5532 4851 3250 5632 4849 3254 
5350 3254 5632 5150 3252 5632 5357 3254 5632 4952 3256 5632 5252 3257 5532 5254 3257 5232 5552 3249 
4950 3252 4832 5354 3252 5432 5352 3248 5432 4848 3248 5232 5155 3249 5532 5151 3255 5032 5149 3257 
5348 3248 5132 5549 3250 5232 5548 3252 5132 5449 3254 4832 5252 3256 5032 5455 3249 5732 5257 3251 
5555 3253 5732 5155 3254 4832 5454 3257 5232 5151 3249 5532 5448 3253 5432 5254 3248 5732 5549 3252 
5749 3254 5132 4850 3251 5332 4956 3254 5632 5755 3249 5232 5049 3249 5432 5353 3252 5032 5256 3254 
4856 3248 5432 5154 3249 5532 5156 3252 5232 5152 3248 5232 5356 3255 5432 4950 3250 5532 5654 3252
```

When I tried printing the raw values from the streamreader directly on the console, it worked correctly but the same method didn't work for initializing the array.

And ideas, suggestions, anything is welcome.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues you are seeing.

First, the order of the inner and outer loops is different in the code that you use to fill the array and the code you use to print the array contents.  In the first case, x is varied in the outer loop and y is varied the inner loop.  The second set up loops vary y in the outer loop and x in the inner loop.  This would seem to explain part of the difference.

More importantly, I noted that that the values in the array as you printed appear to be decimal representations of the ASCII codes of the characters you read.

Be aware that [StreamReader.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an integer value that corresponds to the ASCII value of the next character in the input stream.  When you assign this to a string variable, vb.net converts the integer to a string (as if you used the integer ToString() method).  In this case, the string will contain the decimal value of the ASCII code of the character you originally read instead of the actual character you read.

There are many alternate ways you could accomplish this task.  One way I would suggest is reading the input file in a line at a time using a TextReader, and then using String.Split to get the string representation of each individual number.

Comment: Oh I see, that helps a lot didn't thought encoding would be a problem. String.split() would be clever thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation for the `StreamReader.Read` method?  It returns a single character as an `Integer`, i.e. the Unicode value for a `Char`.  If you want to read the actual numbers in the file then you have to read the substrings and then convert them to `Integer` values yourself.

Something like this seems far more sensible:

```
Dim grid(19, 19) As Integer

Using reader As New StreamReader("file path here")
    For i = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim numbers = reader.ReadLine().Split()

        For j = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(1)
            grid(i, j) = Convert.ToInt32(numbers(j))
        Next
    Next
End Using
```